# How can I getcomponent for a static variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayConversations : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private static PlayConversations instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        conversationTrigger.GetComponent<ConversationTrigger>();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static void ConversationToPlay(int index)
    {
        ConversationTrigger.conversationsToPlay.Add(index);
        instance.StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversations());

    }
}
```

It's not giving me error or exception it's just getting to the line in the Awake:

```
conversationTrigger.GetComponent<ConversationTrigger>();
```

And then continue the game but not the code in the script. Using a breakpoint it does getting to this line but not continue doing the rest of the code.

The script is attached to a GameObject that already have attached the ConversationTrigger script.

Comment: `conversationTrigger` is already a `ConversationTrigger`, so why would you need to get a `ConversationTrigger` from it?

Comment: Right my mistake. I should do : conversationTrigger = GetComponent<ConversationTrigger>(); and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I always use like this. And It works.

```
public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static MyObject Instance = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            DestroyImmediate(Instance.gameObject);
            Instance = this;
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (Instance == this)
        {
            Instance = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And when you want to call your object you must use

```
MyObject x =  MyObject.Instance;
var rb = x.transform.GetComponent<Ridigbody2d>();
```